# Apache: How to set default document to a python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache2, raspberry-pi

I have apache running on a Raspberry Pi. My website is using running Python scripts.  How do I make, say, start.py, as the default document for the site?  In other words, if the host name for the Raspberry Pi is `pi`, I want my users to just use `http://pi` and start.py will execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use apache's `mod_fastcgi` module, mapping a virtual host in apache to a script folder containing python scripts. Note however, this is far from production quality, or secure! However, if your Pi is on a trusted intranet network such as a home, it should be fine.

Here's one blog which spells it out, step by step: http://raspberryserver.blogspot.com/. The final step in the tutorial is to install `apc`, which you can skip. It's for PHP.

Essentially, you'll be able to drop python files into the `/var/www/fastcgi` folder, and profit.